# NSFetchResultsController -controllerDidChangeContent: - Attempt to create two animations for cell with userInfo

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When I go between two tabs in my TabbarController to Viewcontrollers both containg a NSFetchResultsController. I get the following Core Data Error when updating stuff in one of my viewcontrollers:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Attempt to create two animations for cell with userInfo (null)
```

My tableview then becomes white and crashes if I try to update the data.

My -controllerDidChangeContent: looks like this:

1. Viewcontroller (the viewcontroller where I update the data).

   ```
   -(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
   {
   [self.productDetailTableView beginUpdates];
   }


   -(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
   {
   [self.productDetailTableView endUpdates];
   }


   -(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
   {


   UITableView *tableView = self.productDetailTableView;

   switch (type) {
       case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
           [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           break;

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
           [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           break;
      }
   }

    -(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller didChangeObject:   (id)anObject      atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
   {

   UITableView *tableView = self.productDetailTableView;

   NSIndexPath *tvIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:(indexPath.section + 1)];
   NSIndexPath *tvNewIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:(newIndexPath.section + 1)];

   indexPath = tvIndexPath;
   newIndexPath = tvNewIndexPath;
   switch (type) {
       case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

           [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                                                           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

           break;

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                                           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

           break;

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                              arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
           [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                              arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
           break;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Viewcontroller (this viewcontroller where the TableView becomes white and the error occurs).

   ```
   -(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.cartTableView beginUpdates];
    }


   -(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

   UITableView *tableView = self.cartTableView;

   switch(type) {

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
             [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
           break;

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
           break;

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
           [self configureCell:(ProductCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
           break;

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                              arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
           [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                              arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
           break;
    }
   }   

   -(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    UITableView *tableView = self.cartTableView;

   switch(type) {

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
           [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           break;

       case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
           [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           break;
       }
       }


   -(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.cartTableView endUpdates];
    }
   ```

How can fix this issue and get the "Attempt to create two animations for cell with userInfo" go away and what is the reason for this to occur?

Comment: Are you use the same NSFetchedResultsController object for the two view controllers ?

Comment: No 2 seperate NSFetchedResultsControllers. But the same NSMangedObjectContext.

Comment: Did you update the two view controllers at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, I update some objects tied to my first viewcontroller and some in my second.

Comment: I think this code returns the same value for indexPath and newIndexPath check it Please "NSIndexPath *tvIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:(indexPath.section + 1)];
NSIndexPath *tvNewIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:(newIndexPath.section + 1)];

indexPath = tvIndexPath;
newIndexPath = tvNewIndexPath;"

Comment: Can you post the code from your first view controller where you make your changes to the managed object context?

As a guide, this error usually arises if you do something like:

[self.itemList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]];

and then the NSFetchedResultsController tries to do another table animation.

Comment: try clearing cache results `[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:<cacheName>];`

Answer (score 3):

This is not a core data problem, and it is not at all related to core data. It is a tableview problem. CoreData is calling into your delegate methods, and inside there UIKit is throwing an exception because you are trying to animate the same cell twice.

1. Set a symbolic breakpoint for all exceptions and attempt to replicate this behavior. Note that when CoreData is resolving merge conflicts it will throw exceptions that are entirely normal, but the debugger will stop on these. Just keep going until your tableview exception. That will narrow down which table view is the problem.
2. Look at the data that is driving your cell animations. From your code it seems as though you are modifying the index paths before animating. This may be part of the problem. Imagine if you got `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` and `tvIndexPath` was equal to `tvNewIndexPath` . That would produce exactly what you are describing.

CoreData is definitely not the problem here, it's your tableview animations. CoreData is only the messenger.

Comment: Correct.  I'm currently working on a situation where we have a list of documents sorted by date last opened.  When you open a document, core data notifies us that the item has been updated (date last opened changed) and moved (sort position changed).  Simply passing along the updates to the tableview triggers this assertion because the same cell is involved in both updates.  Not sure what the solution is yet...

Answer (score 2):

Things to look at:

a) you should make sure the NSFetchResultsController's delegate is pointing to the correct view controllers; you might have set it up wrong where both the FRCs are pointing to the same view controller, and causing a double animation

b) make sure the controllerWillChangeContent for the view controllers are being called once (or twice) by setting breakpoints

c) notice how your `didChangeObject` code is different for both view controllers? Make sure you know the indexPaths are being setup correctly

If nothing works:
- post code on how the FRCs are setup
- post code on how you are inserting the object into the NSManagedObjectContext

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem in my company's code. I had to write a class that sanitizes the output of the fetch results controller for use in the table view.

The `NSFetchResultsController` API matches so well with the `UITableViewController` API that it seems obvious how they were meant to work together, but **IT'S A TRAP!**  The table view just can't handle all the combinations of updates that the fetch results controller can generate.

In our case, we show a list of documents sorted by date last opened.  When you open a document its `dateLastOpened` field gets changed (triggering an `Update` notification) and its order in the sorted list changes (triggering a `Move` notification).  If you try to apply both of these changes in the same tableView update you'll trigger the infamous assertion.

So my filter class listens to the `NSFetchResultsController` delegate callbacks and records the index paths.  When the updates are completed it converts `Move` events to a `Delete` plus an `Add`, and drops any `Update` events that touch moved or deleted index paths.  The resulting set of changes is applied as a batch to the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the same NSManagedObject, it is possible that didChangeObject will be called on both controllers when data changes.

So, if you are on the first view controller and add an entry, this line will get called:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]                                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

While this animation is happening, this line on the second controller will also get called:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

I think that is why you get an error. You should check the tab that is selected and only call `beginUpdates`, `endUpdates`, `insertRowsAtIndexPath` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` on the controller that is current selected.

You can get the current selected tab using: `tabBarController.selectedIndex`